# React (native) image storing / fetching good practices

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, realm

My use case is a mobile app with react native, but I guess it's very common good practices.

I want to be able, in an app, to take an image (from the camera or the gallery), and to be able to store it so it can be fetched from the date it was added, or some metadata added by the user.

The theory seems quite simple, a way of doing it can be :

- Use any library (eg [this great one](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker)) to get the image,
- Store image as base64 and metadata in, let's say [RealmJS](https://github.com/realm/realm-js) (some internal DB),
- Query this DB to get what I want.

This should work, and should be quite simple to implement.
But I'm wondering about a few things :

- According to the performance of a smartphone's camera, isn't it quite a shame to store it as base64 (and no checksum, more memory used, ...) ?
- This format, base64, isn't a bad idea in general for storing image ?
- Is it a good idea to store the image in RealmJS, as it will be a pain for the user to reuse the image (share it on facebook...), but on the other hand, if I wrote it to the smartphone and store a URI, it can lead to a lot of problems (missing file if the user deletes it, need to access to memory, ...)
- Is this approach "clean" (ok it works, but ...) ?

If you have any experience, tips, or good practice to share, I'll be happy to talk about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can store binary data (images) in Realm. But if you are using Realm locally (not sync), I will suggest that you store the image on the file system and store the path in Realm. Your model could be something like:

```
const ImageSchema = {
    name: 'Image',
    properties: {
        path: 'string',
        created: 'Date',
        modified: 'Date?',
        tags: 'Tag[]'
     }
 };

 const TagSchema = {
     name: 'Tag',
     properties: {
         name: 'string',
         images: { type: 'linkingObjects', objectType: 'Image', property: 'tags' }
     }
};
```

That is, for every image the timestamp for its creation is stored. Moreover, it has an optional timestamp if the image has been modified. The property `path` is where to find the image. If you prefer to store the image, you can use a property of type `data` instead. To find image less that a week old, you can use `realm.objects('Image').filtered('created >= $1', new Date(Date.now()-7*24*60*60))`.

Just for fun, I have added a list of tags for each image. The `linkingObject` in `Tag` makes it possible to find all image which have a particular tag e.g., `realm.objects('Tag').filtered('@links.Tag.name == "Dog"')`.

Comment: Yeah I'll go with something like this, in facts I've already made my schema, and it seems that storing an array of URIs (string) is the most robust way of doing it without putting too much stuff in Realm. 
Thanks for the tips of the linkingObjects !
It opens the doors of many issues (like the user deleting an image through an other app, ....) but in my use case, it seems to be acceptable.